# Writing triggers of a table to automatically update another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I got these tables (Oracle):

```
Doctors (Doctor_ID (PK),
         Doctor_Name,
         DoB,
         Specialization)

Doctors_At_Work (Doctor_ID (PK),
                 The_Date (PK),
                 Hour_Start (PK),
                 Hour_Stop,
                 Room)

Consultations_Intervals (Doctor_ID (PK),
                        The_Date (PK),
                        Start_Hour_Consult (PK),
                        Stop_Hour_Consut,
                        Room)

OBS: A consultation last for only 30 minutes.
```

My task is to create the necessary triggers (insert/update/delete) of `Doctors_At_Work` in order to automatically update the `Consultations_Intervals` table.

What I did so far:

```
Create sequence seq_id_doctor START with 1 INCREMENT BY 1 ORDER NOCACHE;

CREATE OR REPLACE trigger t_1
        BEFORE INSERT ON Doctors_At_Work FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :NEW.Doctor_ID:=seq_id_doctor.NextValue;
   :NEW.The_Date:=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
   :NEW.Hour_Start:=Select Extract (Hour from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE trigger t_2
        AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Consultations_Intervals FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Consultations_Intervals VALUES 
(:NEW.Doctor_ID, :NEW.The_Date, :NEW.Hour_Start, :NEW.Hour_Start + 
  interval '30' minute, :NEW.Room);
END;
/
```

What is wrong with it? How should I solve this task? (if there are other ideas)

Comment: What's the problem? Are you having an error ( what?) or an unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Also, please post the strucure of the tables; for example, Hour_Start is a date, varchar, number?, ...

Answer (score 1):

All you need a simple trigger on your `Doctors_At_work` table. See example below:

Tables:

```
create  table Doctors_At_Work (Doctor_ID number Primary key,
                 The_Date date ,
                 Hour_Start date     ,
                 Hour_Stop date,
                 Room number);

create table Consultations_Intervals (Doctor_ID number,
                        The_Date date ,
                        Start_Hour_Consult number,
                        Stop_Hour_Consut number,
                        Room number);
```

Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger t_1
   before insert or update or delete on doctors_at_work
   for each row
begin
   insert into consultations_intervals (doctor_id,
                                        the_date,
                                        start_hour_consult,
                                        stop_hour_consut,
                                        room)
        values (:new.doctor_id,
                current_timestamp,
                extract (minute from current_timestamp),
                extract (minute from current_timestamp),
                :new.room);
end;
/
```

Output:

```
SQL> Prompt "Before trigger"
"Before trigger"

SQL> select  * from Doctors_At_Work;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from Consultations_Intervals;

no rows selected

SQL> create or replace trigger t_1
   before insert or update or delete on doctors_at_work
  2    3     for each row
  4  begin
   insert into consultations_intervals (doctor_id,
  5    6                                          the_date,
  7                                          start_hour_consult,
  8                                          stop
     .
     .
     .
 Trigger created.

SQL> Insert into DOCTORS_AT_WORK
   (DOCTOR_ID, THE_DATE, HOUR_START, HOUR_STOP, ROOM)
 Values
   (2, TO_DATE('12/18/2016 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('12/13/2016 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('12/14/2016 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 12);
COMMIT;
  2    3    4  
1 row created.

SQL> 
Commit complete.

SQL> select  * from Doctors_At_Work;

 DOCTOR_ID THE_DATE  HOUR_STAR HOUR_STOP       ROOM
---------- --------- --------- --------- ----------
         2 18-DEC-16 13-DEC-16 14-DEC-16         12

SQL> select * from Consultations_Intervals;

 DOCTOR_ID THE_DATE  START_HOUR_CONSULT STOP_HOUR_CONSUT       ROOM
---------- --------- ------------------ ---------------- ----------
         2 19-DEC-16                 17               17         12
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I got 10 doctors, I want to Loop in the trigger t1 for all 10 doctors..I cannot figure out what condition should I write for this loop...

Comment: Are you taking about inserting 10 records to table `Doctors_At_Work`. Is so you can create insert statments. Records will automatically inserted to other table via triger.